# Inline certificate for libcurl instead of using an external bundle?

Tags: c, https, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I am using libcurl for a small c application. The project uses https and requires a validation of both, server and client certificates. I cannot use an option to suppress the verification, since I work in an insecure environment.

I am currently trying to get the server side certificate validated. First attempts gave me an expected error:

```
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

As said an expected error, I understand what the message means. I dug into the documentation of libcurl and found that it supports "certificate bundles", and that younger versions do *not* come with a bundle all. All options I found (and also all explanations) refer to certificate files read at runtime and obviously suggest to include the required CA certificate in the local bundle.

Instead I would prefer to include a single certificate *inline* into the application, so compiled in. This does make sense for this special case, since the application only tries to access a single, hard coded url, so server. I accept that I'd have to replace all deployed copies of the application *if* the server certificate gets changed. However I do not find any options for that in the documentation. I would prefer this strategy, since it allows a much more compact deployment of the application: a single file instead of a structure and runtime configuration.

So my question is: does libcurl offer to include a CA certificate at compile time which can be used at runtime without having to rely on an external bundle?

Answer (score 1):

In `libcurl` the part that verifies certificates is handled by `openssl`. You could use [`SSL_CTX_use_certificate`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_use_certificate.html) to install your certificate at runtime or use `SSL_CTX_set_verify` to overwrite the SSL verification function with your own.

Check [curlx.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curlx.html) for an example.

Comment: Another example that's pretty spot-on is the "CA cert in mem" one: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html

Comment: Looks good so far, I will give it a try. Since I am not exactly familiar with c it will take a little while. But I will report back.